# Get list of drives including shared RDP drives

Tags: c#, wmi, rdp

I am attempting to get a list of all drives that current rdp session has access to. This would include a drive that we provide to them and the drives they share from their local machine. I have tried using WMI  and `DriveInfo` to get the drives but it doesn't seem to return the shared drives. I did notice that the `net use` command can show the shared drives.

Here's what I have tried

```
        try
        {
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath()
            {
                NamespacePath = @"\\"+ clientName + @"\root\cimv2",
                Server = "127.0.0.1"
            };
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path);
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_LogicalDisk");

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
            {
                List<ManagementObject> volume = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().ToList();

                foreach (var vol in volume)
                {
                    if (volume != null)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Is there any way to retrieve this information programatically with C#, if so is WMI how I would do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the TS Client drives by combining information from these two websites

http://www.44342.com/Windows-Terminal-Services-f1018-t1029-p1.htm
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6235/Enumerating-Network-Resources

An example implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ServerEnumDemo
{
    public sealed class TsClientSharesProvider : IDisposable
    {
        private IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        private IList<string> result;
        public IEnumerable<string> GetUncPaths()
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            result = new List<string>();
            EnumerateTsclientShares(result, new Win32.NETRESOURCE());
            return result;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.WNetCloseEnum(handle);
                handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        private void EnumerateTsclientShares(ICollection<string> result, Win32.NETRESOURCE pRsrc)
        {
            uint bufferSize = 16384;
            buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bufferSize);
            uint cEntries = 1;


            var returncode = Win32.WNetOpenEnum(Win32.ResourceScope.RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, Win32.ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
                Win32.ResourceUsage.RESOURCEUSAGE_ALL, pRsrc, out handle);

            if (returncode != Win32.ErrorCodes.NO_ERROR)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not enumerate network shares");
            }

            do
            {
                returncode = Win32.WNetEnumResource(handle, ref cEntries, buffer, ref bufferSize);

                if (returncode == Win32.ErrorCodes.NO_ERROR)
                {
                    Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, pRsrc);
                    if ((pRsrc.dwUsage == Win32.ResourceUsage.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE)
                        && pRsrc.lpLocalName.Contains("tsclient"))
                    {
                        result.Add(pRsrc.lpLocalName);
                    }

                    if ((pRsrc.dwUsage & Win32.ResourceUsage.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER) ==
                        Win32.ResourceUsage.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER)
                    {
                        EnumerateTsclientShares(result, pRsrc);
                    }
                }
                else if (returncode != Win32.ErrorCodes.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR " + returncode);
                }
            } while (returncode != Win32.ErrorCodes.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding Win32 bindings:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ServerEnumDemo
{
    public static class Win32
    {
        [DllImport("Mpr.dll", EntryPoint = "WNetOpenEnumA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        internal static extern ErrorCodes WNetOpenEnum(ResourceScope dwScope, ResourceType dwType, ResourceUsage dwUsage,
            NETRESOURCE p, out IntPtr lphEnum);

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll", EntryPoint = "WNetCloseEnum", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        internal static extern ErrorCodes WNetCloseEnum(IntPtr hEnum);

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll", EntryPoint = "WNetEnumResourceA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        internal static extern ErrorCodes WNetEnumResource(IntPtr hEnum, ref uint lpcCount, IntPtr buffer,
            ref uint lpBufferSize);

        public enum ResourceDisplayType
        {
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE,
            RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal class NETRESOURCE
        {
            public ResourceDisplayType dwDisplayType = 0;
            public ResourceScope dwScope = 0;
            public ResourceType dwType = 0;
            public ResourceUsage dwUsage = 0;
            public string lpComment = null;
            public string lpLocalName = null;
            public string lpProvider = null;
            public string lpRemoteName = null;
        }

        public enum ResourceUsage
        {
            RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010,
            RESOURCEUSAGE_ALL = (RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE | RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER | RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED),
        };

        public enum ResourceScope
        {
            RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 1,
            RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
            RESOURCE_REMEMBERED,
            RESOURCE_RECENT,
            RESOURCE_CONTEXT
        };

        public enum ResourceType
        {
            RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
            RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            RESOURCETYPE_PRINT,
            RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED
        };

        internal enum ErrorCodes
        {
            NO_ERROR = 0,
            ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: order of fields for NETRESOURCE is wrong here, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342437